# Why is MoonSharp DoString leaking memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, lua

I'm using [MoonSharp](http://www.moonsharp.org/about.html) (1.6.0, just updated, had the problem before it too) under .NET 4.6. I have the following C# code:

```
public class LuaCore {
    public static Script script = new Script();
    public static DynValue Call(string func)
    {
        return script.DoString(func);
    }
}
```

It seems like whenever I call `LuaCore.Call("any code")` additional ~1.5 kilobytes are used by the program. This also happens then the `any code` is `stuff = nil`, hence "any code".
When this is called about ~3500 times per second, an additional 25 megabytes are used every five seconds, and the call per second is depending on the power of the machine. Since multiple calls would be used per update, the memory usage of the program would also increase faster (tested this). After 5 minutes, I get an OutOfMemoryException (with 1.4GB used).
I took a snapshot of the heap with the app using 1.5GB of ram. It seems that the interpreter is storing each source code that was called, or it looks like that with VS's diagnostic tools.
[image: Memory heap from snapshot]

Why is MoonSharp storing that much data with each call?

Comment: Take memory profiler and see what objects are held in memory and who hold them. It will be much easier to answer your question after that

Comment: I've added some details and a screenshot with the objects held in ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer : you are (likely) calling the wrong API for what you are trying to do.
DoString loads the specified code inside the specified Script context and runs it. If you pass the same code over and over you are just loading more and more copies of it.

So there are two options, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

1. You are using LuaCore.Call to invoke a script which is different everytime : use `Script.RunString(code)` - it's a static method and doesn't preserve any state from one run to another
2. You are using `LuaCore.Call` to invoke the same script over and over : Call `DynValue ret = script.LoadString(code)` once and then `script.Call(ret)` over and over.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately neither helped. The first approach does not let me have any context and data made outside that function, the second one would only work if I wanted to pass exactly the same code during each call which I do not since there are some little changes.

Comment: Then your only chance is to create separate Script objects and use a "naked" table (or a userdata of your choice) for data to be shared between instances. Note that you cannot share normal tables, because functions belong to a specific script.
Creating a Script object is not a lightweight operation, so doing that every frame is likely too expensive.. but this begs the question - why are you doing little changes to the script every frame in the first place ?

Comment: Just some contextual changes, positions, etc. So promoting the script to a lua function and then Call()-ing it with parameters would not have them stored each time it's called, saving memory (and maybe performance)?

Comment: Absolutely. You can use parameters, or you can set new globals for example, or you can have a C# class exposed to Lua using your variables.. if you keep the code the same across calls, it's much faster as it doesn't have to recompile the script everytime, etc.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working now. Also I got a 25% performance increase since it calls the function from memory.